# Objective-C - Save all web request and execute them after having internet connection

Tags: objective-c, xcode, api, request, save

In Objective-c, is there possible to save all the web request ( api calls, for saving data per example ) and execute them all when user have internet connection?

Is there any global word to describe what i want?
My english is poor so i can't explain myself clearly

Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  Save the request parameters to a plist when offline.  Then when online, read the parameters into your request and fire away.